# Getting contents of square brackets with regex, including nested ones

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to have this:

```
[one[two]][three]
```

And extract this with a regex?

```
Array (
    [0] => one[two]
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this cannot be done with a single standard regex statement. In general, regex does not handle nested or recursive text well.

Comment: You might do better by asking for a solution to your actual problem, rather than assuming part of the answer in your question by asking for a regex solution (especially when no regex solution actually exists).

Comment: @Mark Byers: Yes, PHP
@Anthony Forloney: What is that? I don't know how it works.
@Andrew Aylett: Is related to a problem I have to WordPress I have asked before:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2564177/wordpress-problem-with-the-shortcode-regex
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398445/wordpress-insert-shortcodes-inside-attributes-of-other-shortcodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For PHP you can use recursion in regular expressions that *nearly* gives you what you want:

```
$s = 'abc [one[two]][three] def';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\[(?:[^][]|(?R))*\]/', $s, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [one[two]]
            [1] => [three]
        )

)
```

For something more advanced than this, it's probably best not to use regular expressions.

Comment: voting -- nothing fits better

Comment: What do you mean by *nearly*?

Comment: @EmanuilRusev: The structure of the result is not quite the same as the desired result that the OP wanted in the question.

Comment: @MarkByers, thanks for the response and for the great answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the regex with a loop, for example,

1. Match all `\[([^\]]*)\]`.
2. For each match, replace `\x01` with `[` and `\x02` with `]` and output the result.
3. Replace all of `\[([^\]]*)\]` into `\x01$1\x02` (**warning**: assumes `\x01` and `\x02` are not used by the string.)
4. Repeat 1 until there's no match.

But I'd write a string scanner for this problem :).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Data::Dumper;
@a = ();
$re = qr/\[((?:[^][]|(??{$re}))*)\](?{push@a,$^N})/;
'[one[two]][three]' =~ /$re*/;
print Dumper \@a;
# $VAR1 = [
#           'two',
#           'one[two]',
#           'three'
#         ];
```

Not *exactly* what you asked for, but it's kinda doable with (ir)regular expression extensions.  (Perl 5.10's `(?PARNO)` can replace the usage of `(??{CODE})`.)

Answer (score 0):

In Perl 5.10 regex, you can use named backtracking and a recursive subroutine to do that:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$re = qr  /
     (                      # start capture buffer 1
        \[                  #   match an opening brace
        (                   # capture buffer 2
        (?:                 #   match one of:
            (?>             #     don't backtrack over the inside of this group
                [^\[\]]+    #       one or more non braces
            )               #     end non backtracking group
        |                   #     ... or ...
            (?1)            #     recurse to bracket 1 and try it again
        )*                  #   0 or more times.
        )                   # end buffer 2
        \]                  #   match a closing brace
     )                      # end capture buffer one
    /x;


print "\n\n"; 

sub strip {
my ($str) = @_;
while ($str=~/$re/g) {
    $match=$1; $striped=$2;
    print "$striped\n";
    strip($striped) if $striped=~/\[/;
    return $striped;
}
}


$str="[one[two]][three][[four]five][[[six]seven]eight]";

print "start=$str\n";

while ($str=~/$re/g) { 
    strip($1) ;
}
```

Output:

```
start=[one[two]][three][[four]five][[[six]seven]eight]
one[two]
two
three
[four]five
four
[[six]seven]eight
[six]seven
six
```